# Way to record the last n minute from webcam

Tags: webcam, image-processing, opencv

I try to use or create a software to record the last n minutes from a webcam.

I use opencv to grab images from my webcam but I don't know if it is the best way to create a in real time a video. I want to continiously record the data and then when the user want it, the program stop and generate a video with the last n minutes.

I planned to record the m last frames in memory or in computer and continously replace the older frame by new one and when the user want its video, generate it with the frames.

I am not really sure it is the best and efficious way to do that.

Can someone give me link or advice about doing somethink like that?

Comment: I bet the only thing a user would be interested in, would be when movement occurs. Most webcam programs have a setting to automatically record when movement is detected, and stop when movement has stopped. This will create only a few clips, even if the user is not looking. A script can then remove files that are older than x hours/days/etc... I think that would be the best route for you to go. The benefit of this is that if movement spans more than a minute or so, you have everything, not just the last x minutes

Comment: In fact I really want to record that last n minutes because my camera is moving. It is not a security camera like problems. I thought I would be able to do that with a ffmpeg streaming server. Is it possible to configure a streaming server to do this?